Venn diagram in R with VennDiagram remove label line
I am constructing Venn diagrams in R using the VennDiagram package.
In the example below the plot gives me the cross.area=7 with a long line instead of placing the number inside the overlapping area between the groups. It seems silly when there is plenty of room to put "7" in the area.
Is there a way to change this, for instance by setting a higher area size between the groups or setting label lines to FALSE or something like that?
library("VennDiagram")

grid.newpage() 
vennplot.ihdstroke <- draw.pairwise.venn(area1=212, area2=57,  
                       cross.area=7, category=c("area1","area2"), 
                       col="Black",fill=c("#999999", #E69F00"),lty="blank", cex = .8, 
                       fontface = "italic")



If you want to remove the line you have to add ext.line.lty = 0, additionally you can position the number for the overlap manually inside the overlapping area with ext.dist = -0.305.
library("VennDiagram")

grid.newpage()
vennplot.ihdstroke <- draw.pairwise.venn(
  area1 = 212,
  area2 = 57,
  cross.area = 7,
  category = c("area1", "area2"),
  col = "Black",
  fill = c("#999999", "#E69F00"),
  lty = "blank",
  cex = .8,
  fontface = "italic",
  ext.line.lty  = 0,
  ext.dist = -0.305
)

